# Electronic properties of neurons

Tags: physiology

This is about the electronic properties of neurons.

When a signal is sent from 1 part of the brain due to a stimulus,are neurons considered voltage or current sources?

Comment: Can you please provide context of what you already know and what you've read trying to answer your question? As written, it doesn't make much sense in the context of biology.

Comment: It is necessary to study the known substitution circuits of neurons - these are representations of neurons in the form of equivalent electrical circuits, where capacitances, inductances, or others imitate the potential-current properties of membranes and other conductive elements